# How to recolour a Sprite

Tags: flutter, dart, sprite, flame

I am trying to figure out how to recolour or 'tint' a Sprite using the Flame engine for Flutter. I've tried to add or override a Paint object as described here: [How to Add transparency to image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61689984/how-to-add-transparency-to-image).

Using the code below I tried changing the Paint object using a different color than white. The alpha does change, but my Sprite image stays white. My source image is a white png.

```dart
void render(Canvas c) {
  Sprite spriteImg = Sprite('someImg.png');
  rect = Rect.fromLTWH(10, 10, 20, 20);
  Paint redPaint = Paint()..color = Colors.red.withOpacity(0.5);
  spriteImg.renderRect(c, rect, overridePaint: redPaint);
}
```

The Flame engine must have a way to tint Sprites that I'm not seeing or using wrong right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `ColorEffect` for that:

```dart
yourSpriteComponent
  ..add(
    ColorEffect(
      Colors.red,
      const Offset(
        0.0,
        0.5,
      ), // Means, applies from 0% to 50% of the color
      EffectController(
        duration: 1.5,
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm still getting the hang of Flame, but it seems like to works a lot like SpriteKit with effects like these, yet it resembles the Flutter like structure. Pretty neat! Do you know if there's a way to 'permanently' color a `Sprite`? I don't really understand what the `Paint` object is doing on `SpriteComponent` if I can only seem to make it change alpha.

Comment: You can try to do `paint.tint(color)`, that is basically what the `ColorEffect` is doing.

Comment: @spydon Tint is working great, but how about paint method, it seems not working. What is the usage for it? `MyComponent()..paint.color = Colors.red`  <== not working

Comment: I don't know what type of `Component` that your `MyComponent` is, but if you have only added the `HasPaint` mixin that doesn't do anything automatically, it just adds a `paint` field on your class that you can use for whatever you'd like.